# React JS app freezing when useEffect is used

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My React application started freezing when changing tabs with items previously set by useEffect by reading index tab and filtering array against item's categoryID. The reason is useEffect () but I have no other idea how to otherwise create a realtime array refresh depending on where the user clicks. There is no error in console.

I must add that the application was working normally a couple of minutes earlier.

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    if(value && shopProducts){
      const filtered = shopProducts.filter(item => item.categoryID === value)
      setUserChoose(() => filtered)
    }else if(value === 0 && shopProducts){
      const filtered = shopProducts.filter(item => item.categoryID === value)
      setUserChoose(() => filtered)
    }
  }, [value, shopProducts])
```

Items maping

```
<TabPanel value={0} index={0}>
            {userChoose.map((item, index) => {
              return(
                <DishComponent name={item.name} price={item.price} description={item.description} id={item.id} img={item.img} clickedData={setItem}/>
              )
              })}
            </TabPanel>
            <TabPanel value={1} index={1}>
            {userChoose.map((item, index) => {
              return(
                <DishComponent name={item.name} price={item.price} description={item.description} id={item.id} img={item.img} clickedData={setItem}/>
              )
              })}
            </TabPanel>
            <TabPanel value={2} index={2}>
            {userChoose.map((item, index) => {
              return(
                <DishComponent name={item.name} price={item.price} description={item.description} id={item.id} img={item.img} clickedData={setItem}/>
              )
              })}
            </TabPanel>
```

Dish Component

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'

import './dish.css'

const DishComponent = ({name,price,description,id, img, shopID, clickedData}) => {



  return (
    <>
    <div className='dish-component' onClick={clickedData([{name: name, id: id, price: price}])}>
        <div className='right-content'>
            <p>{name}</p>
            <p style={{marginTop: '-15px'}}>{price} eur.</p>
            <p style={{color: 'gray',marginTop: '-15px'}}>{description}</p>
        </div>
        <div className='left-content'>
            <img className='img' alt={name} src={img}/>
        </div>
    </div>



    </>
  )
}

export default DishComponent
```

Comment: for filtering data, you can make use of the derived state, having the `value` in state ... feel free to add a working sample of what you tried (use codesandbox, save code and share the link here)...

Answer (score 0):

I got that. For first deleted this bunch of code.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if(value && shopProducts){
      const filtered = shopProducts.filter(item => item.categoryID === value)
      setUserChoose(() => filtered)
    }else if(value === 0 && shopProducts){
      const filtered = shopProducts.filter(item => item.categoryID === value)
      setUserChoose(() => filtered)
    }
  }, [value, shopProducts])
```

I did a resarch on useMemo () and useCallback (). I used useMemo () in this case because it doesn't re-render until it finds a value change in state.

```
 useMemo(() => {
     const filtred = shopProducts.filter((item) => item.categoryID === value)
     setUserChoose(() => filtred)
 },[value, shopProducts])
```

And next i changed my code inside dishcomponent.js. To setup array with previous items and new items.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'

import './dish.css'

const DishComponent = ({name,price,description,id, img, shopID, setItem}) => {


  const setup = () => {
    setItem((prev) => [...prev, {name: name,price: price,id:id, shopID:shopID}])
  }

  return (
    <>
    <div className='dish-component' onClick={() => setup()}>
        <div className='right-content'>
            <p>{name}</p>
            <p style={{marginTop: '-15px'}}>{price} eur.</p>
            <p style={{color: 'gray',marginTop: '-15px'}}>{description}</p>
        </div>
        <div className='left-content'>
            <img className='img' alt={name} src={img}/>
        </div>
    </div>



    </>
  )
}

export default DishComponent
```